# PHP generate a random number using todays date

Tags: php, date, random, time

I am trying to assign a block of content (on a webpage) a randomly generated number that is based between todays date (whatever that will be) and a fixed number. For some reason there is dramatic difference in the sorts of numbers being outputted. For example when I test my code locally the numbers generated are good enough for me (in the positive) but when on an actual live server they are generally the opposite and are negative numbers.

This is my one liner:

```
<?php $today=date('YmdHi'); echo rand(201203140906, $today); ?>
```

Basically '201203140906' is the Year, Month, Day, Hour.

Is this good or bad? Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Could you use timestamps? And don't use `rand()`, but use `mt_rand()`. You can also run `mt_getrandmax()` to see the largest value from `mt_rand()`. I'd also ask why you're trying to do this? Seems odd to find the value between a date, and a fixed number, a date I can understand.

Comment: Are you trying to seed the random number generator with the date so that the content randomizes each day?

Comment: I'm not great with PHP you see so half of the above didn't make much sense :( I'm just trying to ensure one block of content is ordered randomly on the page amongst other blocks that are in date order. Thats the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 32-bit system, the largest value that can be held in an INT is  2147483647.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

If your local machine is 64 bit and your server is 32 bit, they will have different size limits. The server will not be able to handle an integer as large as 201203140906.

You may be able to randomly generate a smaller number and then add that to 201203140906.

Like this perhaps:

```
$today = date('YmdHi');
$startDate = date('YmdHi', strtotime('2012-03-14 09:06:00'));
$range = $today - $startDate;
$rand = rand(0, $range);
echo "$rand and " . ($startDate + $rand);
```

OR you can do this to generate a random date in the last ten days:

```
$today = date('YmdHi');
$startDate = date('YmdHi', strtotime('-10 days'));
$range = $today - $startDate;
$rand = rand(0, $range);
echo "$rand and " . ($startDate + $rand);
```

Comment: How might I do this exactly? I'm not so good with PHP and would appreciate some help on getting this working...

Comment: My only issue with this method is that over time the block of content will display lower down the page because the difference between my fixed date/number and the actual date will grow. Its not an ideal solution. Thanks.

Comment: Then you don't want "a randomly generated number that is based between todays date and a fixed number"? That's what you asked for in your question.

Comment: I've added code to get a random date in the last ten days. That should keep your inserted content near the top, assuming your content is ordered newest to oldest. And obviously you can change the "10" to however many days are appropriate.

Comment: Too true, that is exactly what I asked but your new answer is perfect. I haven't got time to implement now but will try it when I get a moment. I will write my questions a little more specific next time! Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$then = strtotime('2012-03-14 09:06:00'); 
$now = time();
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) echo date('YmdHi', rand($then, $now)), '<br>'; 
?>
```

By the way... you could also be using "uniqid()"

Comment: Great, thanks for this. One problem though is that it just outputs a whole list of different numbers, for example '201205140021<br>201203151132<br> ... etc.' How can I modify this so it just outputs just one random number?

Answer (score 0):

Given your explanation in the comments you can probably solve your problem with the [shuffle()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function. You could have two arrays, one the list of dates and the other the data you wish to spread randomly and then simply read from the shuffled data. Since there's no code example I'll leave the details to you.